# Ruby mysql2 gem query string interpolation

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I have a database table **data**

```
data, TEXT
source, VARCHAR(20)
count, INT
```

I am using `mysql2` gem and try to insert data into this table the following way:

```
def insert(data, source, count=0)
    result = client.query(
        "INSERT INTO data (data, source, count) VALUES ('#{client.escape(data)}', '#{client.escape(source)}', #{count})"
    )
end
```

This produces the following error:
`no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)`

I know it's a problem with `passwords` but I would like to know 2 things. How can I make it work and is there a cleaner way to build this query string ? Something like:

```
query_s = "INSERT INTO data (data, source, count) VALUES (?,?,?)", [data, source, count]
client.query(query_s)
```

Comment: Not enough information to debug exactly what's going on, and I think you mean "interpolation" not "extrapolation".  But I would suggest you use [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) with the mysql2 adapter, instead of the raw mysql2 adapter directly. Sequel will give you the cleaner way to do it. I don't know if one exists in the mysql2 adapter directly. The mysql2 adapter directly is pretty low-level, you'll be happier with it wrapped in Sequel.

Comment: I'm 100% with @jrochkind here. Interfacing with the MySQL driver is really ugly and full of problems. Use a database layer like Sequel or ActiveRecord and your life will be a lot easier. The driver is provided for those who are writing things like Sequel or ActiveRecord and isn't intended to be used directly.

Comment: I have it working now. I used Sequel, cool gem btw. Apparently the problem was calling the method `insert(data, source, my_hash[:count])`. I didn't knew Ruby cannot handle arguments like that.

Comment: ruby can handle arguments like that. It depends on what the #insert method you were calling expected as far as the placement and type of arguments, apparently not what you were giving it.